# How to close a file which is opened to read in an API Call

Tags: python, json, api

```
import glob
import os
import requests
import shutil


class file_service:
    
    def file():
        dir_name = '/Users/TEST/Downloads/TU'
        os.chdir(dir_name)

        pattern='TU_*.csv'

        for x in glob.glob(pattern):
            file_name=os.path.join(dir_name,x)
            print (file_name)
        from datetime import date
        dir_name_backup = '/Users/Zill/Downloads/backup'
        today = date.today()
        backup_file_name = f'Backup_TU_{today.year}{today.month:02}{today.day:02}.csv'
        backup_file_name_directory= os.path.join(dir_name_backup,backup_file_name)
        print(backup_file_name_directory)
        newPath = shutil.copy(file_name, backup_file_name_directory)
        url = "google.com"

        payload = {'name': 'file'}
        files = [
        ('file', open(file_name,'rb'))
        
        ]
        headers = {
        'X-API-TOKEN': '12312'
        }

        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)

        print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
        
        files.close()
        os.remove(file_name)


    file()
```

To provide an overall context, I am trying to retrieve a file from my OS and using POST method I am trying to post the content of the file into an application. Its working as expected so far, the details are getting pushed into application as expected. As part of my next step I am trying to remove the file from my existing directory using os.remove(). But I am getting a Win32 error as my file is not closed when it was opened in read-only mode in the POST call. I am trying to close it but I am unable to do so.

Can anyone please help me out with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you try to use `with` statement like `with open(file_name) as f:`

Comment: @general03 can we use with a statement within the JSON? I have not done that before. Can you please elaborate further

Comment: I'm a bit confused: What does `files.close()` exactly do?

Comment: @Timus it helps in closing the file which has been opened for reading purpose. Unfortunately my API call is opening the file in an JSON array itself because of which I am unable to close it.

Comment: Doesn't `open(file_name,'rb')` in the list comprehension give you the `fd`s for closing later?

Comment: I couldn't find any. Also please note that I am not an advanced level user. I am still working my way through to learn a bit of python scripting @Timus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your code correctly. Could you try replacing

```
files.close()
```

with

```
for _, file in files:
    file.close()
```

and check if it works?

**Explanation**:
In

```
 files = [('file', open(file_name,'rb'))]
```

you create a list containing exactly one tuple that has the *string* `'file'` as first element and a [`file` object](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-file-object) as second element:

```
[('file', file_object)]
```

The loop takes the tuple from the list, ignores its first element (`_`), takes its second element, the `file` object, and uses its [`close` method](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/io.html#io.IOBase.close) to close it.

I've just now realised the list contains only *one* tuple. So there's no need for a loop:

```
files[0][1].close()
```

should do it.

The best way would be to use `with` (the file gets automatically closed once you leave the `with` block):

```
        payload = {'name': 'file'}
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as file:

            files = [('file', file)]
            headers = {'X-API-TOKEN': '12312'}
            response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)
            print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
        
        os.remove(file_name)
```

Comment: Can you explain what your for loop is doing actually?

Comment: @AanuragDas See my edit. The loop is actually not necessary, since the list contains only one element (_files_ sounded like more files).